# Pandas vectorized implementation of a simple operation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Scheme': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Fuel_remaining': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'correction': [0.25, 0.333333333, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['fuel_usage'] = df['Fuel_remaining']*df['correction'] + 0.01
```

Above is small snippet. I wish to have correct fuel_usage for each row, in above I am making a mistake i.e in first row the fuel usage is 5*0.25 = 1.25, this need to be removed from Fuel remaining when computing for second row. The same way for row 3, need to remove fuel usage for row 1 and row 2 and so on.... If the pandas dataframe is huge, does it make sense to compute one row at a time use shift and then compute second row and so on? Or there can be better way?

Ideal output would be this (Not what I am getting in above snippet):

```
data = {'Scheme': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'fuel_usage': [1.26, 1.256667, 1.102667, 0.617493, 0.345796], 'correction': [0.25, 0.333333333, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput to question?

Comment: In the question you've mentioned "first row the fuel usage is 5*0.25 = 1.25, this need to be removed from Fuel remaining when computing for second row." In the desired output, you've mentioned fuel_remaining for 2nd row as 5. If my understanding is correct,Shouldn't it be 3.75 ie (5-1.25)?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

We can update fuel usuage with simple loop; Try this;

```
fuel_usage = []

for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    if i == 0:
        num = df["Fuel_remaining"][i] * df['correction'][i]
        fuel_usage.append(num)
    else:
        num = (df["Fuel_remaining"][i] - num) * df['correction'][i]
        fuel_usage.append(num)
        num = sum(fuel_usage)
df["fuel_usage"] = fuel_usage
del df["Fuel_remaining"]
```

Output of df;

[image]

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Speed things up by using numpy arrays: `fual_usage = np.zeros(len(df))`, `fual_usage[i]=num` and `num = fual_usage.sum()`

Comment: For 20,000 records, it took 7.1 seconds using lists, 0.4 seconds using numpy array

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a mathematical answer, but hope you follow me.

Let's call the remaining fuel: `f_0, ..., f_n`, corrections `c_0, ..., c_n` and fuel usage `u_0, ..., u_n`. Notice that the usage is the fuel times the correction at row `i`. And the remaining fuel at row `i` is the fuel at row `i-1` minus the usage at row `i-1`.

The formula for `u_i` is as follows:

[image]

This can be further reduced to: `u_i = c_i(1-c_{i-1})* ... *(1-c_0)f_0` which depends only on the corrections and the initial fuel. By doing:

```
df['times'] = (1 - df['correction']).cumprod().shift().fillna(1)
```

We compute the factor `(1-c_{i-1})* ... *(1-c_0)` at row `i` such that we can compute the fuel usage column by multiplying the intitial fuel with the column `times` and `correction`:

```
fuel = 5
df['fuel_usage'] = fuel * df.times * df.correction
```

Output:

```
  Scheme  Fuel_remaining  correction   times  fuel_usage
0      A               5    0.250000  1.0000     1.25000
1      A               5    0.333333  0.7500     1.25000
2      A               5    0.440000  0.5000     1.10000
3      A               5    0.440000  0.2800     0.61600
4      A               5    0.440000  0.1568     0.34496
```

Comment: My apologies, I was making an error. u_i = c_i*f_i + 0.01, so trying to bring this (0.01) into formulation. But, what you have shown answers my original question. Have updated the question by correcting my mistake.

Comment: This makes things substantially more difficult. I tried finding a pattern, but it did not work out. Maybe you are more lucky on the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Try adding `c` to the equation and work it out. I find that you need to do the same multiplication as above, but you need to add something in the form of `+c(1 - c_i(combination of corrections))`. As it answers you original question, could you mark it as so?